# How does "options" in shell scripting work?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, options

I found some code in one of the answers here and accommodated it to my needs but now I have two questions:

**Q1:** how can I display the options text after the code in case statement finishes? So the user can see the options again.

**Q2:** Can I make it so that every option is displayed on its own line when I run the script? Currently it is not.

```
options=(
        "quit/exit"
    "new rational db"
    "run php for rational codebase"
    "run php for playground codebase"
   )

select option in "${options[@]}"; do
  case "$REPLY" in
       1) break;;
       2) sudo -i -u db2inst1 bash -c "db2stop force;";;
       3) rm /tmp/createDb2*;;
       4)  ;;               
  esac
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: add spaces to the end of any of the options to make it longer than 40 characters, for example:

```
options=(
        "quit/exit"
    "new rational db"
    "run php for rational codebase"
    "run php for playground codebase                       "
   )
```

Q2: Not sure if there is a more elegant way (didn't see in `help select`), but this should work:

```
finished=
while test ! "$finished"; do
    select option in "${options[@]}"; do
      case "$REPLY" in
           1) finished=1;;
           2) sudo -i -u db2inst1 bash -c "db2stop force;";;
           3) rm /tmp/createDb2*;;
           4)  ;;               
      esac
      break
    done
done
```